# NSData to Struct messing up data

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, struct, nsdata

So I have 2 structs, Level and Item. When i try to read the level struct everything works. But once i try to load an item my values get messed up. I've got this hex-values:

```
    Level-Struct| Item-Struct 
    spRot|count | type | anchorX: 25 | anchorY:375 |count
... 00 00 05 00   00 00 19 00   00 00 77 01   00 00 04 00 ...
```

After reading the data into a struct the values are:

```
type = 0
anchorX = 24576000
anchorY = 262144
pointCount = 0
```

it seems that it "fills" type correctly with 0 but is then going on using 00 00 77 01 (which is 24576000) instead of the correct 19 00 00 00 (25). How can i get my program to read it correct? Here are the important parts of the source:

```
typedef struct ItemPoint {
    SInt32 x;
    SInt32 y;
} ItemPoint;

typedef struct Item {
    UInt16 type;
    UInt32 anchorX;
    UInt32 anchorY;
    UInt32 pointCount;
    ItemPoint *points;
} Item;

typedef struct LevelStruct {
    UInt32 width;
    UInt32 height;
    UInt32 spawnX;
    UInt32 spawnY;
    UInt16 spawnRot;
    UInt16 itemCount;
    void *items;
} LevelStruct;



// Test Function

LevelStruct level;
NSUInteger byteOffset = 20;
[data getBytes:&level length:byteOffset];
BlockPolygon *poly = malloc(sizeof(BlockPolygon));
[data getBytes:poly range:NSMakeRange(byteOffset, 14)];
```

Comment: You might need to set packing on your struct to packed.  Add `__attribute__((packed))` in between the ending } and your struct name.  See if that helps.  Byte alignment is a pain.

Comment: @Putz1103, you should make an answer. The underlying issue is that there is no default promise on the alignment of struct members. Note that there can be some performance impact of doing this (the compiler aligns structure elements for a reason…)

Comment: I don't think `__attribute__((packed))` in isolation will help in any way. It all depends how the struct is *written* into the NSData object and how it is *read*. The *read* simply needs to be the *inverse* function of *write*.

Comment: @CouchDeveloper I actually agree and contemplated changing my answer. If it is being packed, it is generally to store to disk or transferred across the network, in which case byte order should be taken into consideration. If this NSData object only lives in memory in this application the `__attribute__((__packed__))` will only reduce performance.

Comment: minor suggestion, you may want to send and store your multi-byte numbers in **Network Byte Order**. Despite it being big endian and require conversion on common platforms, it is used across the entire Internet as part of TCP/IP stack, and operating system libraries have speedy conversion functions and macros to convert them. This can make your code easily portable to things like PPC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to marshal your structs you should declare them as packed and use `sizeof` instead of magic numbers.

```
typedef struct __attribute__((__packed__)) ItemPoint {
    SInt32 x;
    SInt32 y;
} ItemPoint;

typedef struct __attribute__((__packed__)) Item {
    UInt16 type;
    UInt32 anchorX;
    UInt32 anchorY;
    UInt32 pointCount;
    ItemPoint *points;
} Item;

typedef struct __attribute__((__packed__)) LevelStruct {
    UInt32 width;
    UInt32 height;
    UInt32 spawnX;
    UInt32 spawnY;
    UInt16 spawnRot;
    UInt16 itemCount;
    void *items;
} LevelStruct;



// Test Function    
LevelStruct level;
size_t length = sizeof(LevelStruct);
size_t offset = 0;

[data getBytes:&level length:length];

offset += length;
length = sizeof(BlockPolygon);

BlockPolygon *poly = malloc(length);
[data getBytes:poly range:NSMakeRange(offset, length)];
```

Answer (score 3):

You might need to set packing on your struct to packed. Add `__attribute__((packed))` in between the ending } and your struct name. See if that helps. Byte alignment is a pain.

```
typedef struct
{

} __attribute__((packed)) structName;
```

If you are reading straight from a binary file then you either need to save that file with the same byte alignment as you are reading, or make the file have a byte alignment of 1 (packed as small as possible, not buffer bytes to align to 8 or any other number) and add the `packed` attribute to your structs.